# While executing a java project jar from terminal getting the error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am writing my java code in `Android Studio` for `appium` and was able to execute it from `Android Studio` successfully and I am converting the code to a jar. After converting to jar and i am trying to execute the `jar` from terminal by executing this

```
java -jar abc.jar
```

from the project code location and getting this error

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add required jar to classpath like this:

```
set CLASSPATH=<path-to-app>/myapp.jar;<path-to-app>/lib/json.jar;.
java MyApp
```

[Selenium jar should be there](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)